# How do i open a video instead of displaying the video for the user to click on it?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, video-streaming

I want to create an app where you have different videos linked to a tableview. However every time i try to link the video in the viewcontroller it just shows a square with a video preview picture on it and a triangle to click for play on it. However i want to autostart playing it like selecting a music track in the default ios music app.

```
var html = "<html><body><iframesrc=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/G1OGNZR3bhA\"frameborder=\"0\" ></iframe></body></html>"

WebView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instead of a webview?

Comment: Could you explain? Im kinda novice into developping apps O:)

Comment: https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mpmovieplayerviewcontroller%20example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `MPMoviePlayerViewcontroller` to load your video from an url into a subview:

```
var moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
        moviePlayer!.view.frame = CGRect(x: X, y: Y, width: W, height: H)
        moviePlayer!.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Unknown
        moviePlayer!.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded


            self.moviePlayer!.contentURL = yourUrl
            self.moviePlayer!.prepareToPlay()
            self.moviePlayer!.play()


        view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
```